# C# Format By User Choice?

Tags: c#, string, variables, textbox, integer

I have a very simple weight loss conversion program, I simply want to get the users input from a text box convert it to int and in the format area where it says for example

```
if (comboBoxFrom.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ST" && comboBoxTo.SelectedItem.ToString() == "KG")
{
    double conver = userInput * 6.35;
    txtBoxResult.Text = "Converted Amount : " + conver.ToString("N2"); ;
}
```

Is there anyway I can make N(insert variable here) at all? I just want it to be more dynamic.

Comment: Whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: I wish to let the user choose how many decimal places the result conversion rate goes to. I have a box that grabs there input and parses it to int, so I want conver.ToString and make the N be the variable the user chose. Is this possible?

Comment: `[...] conver.ToString("N" + decimalPlaces);` Or `.ToString($"N{decimalPlaces}"`

Comment: God dammit, I had that in my head and basically typed it but didn't know how to write it. Thanks a ton! What should I put in to be a failsafe so the program continues converting if the user enters nothing or enter non numerical character?

Comment: This worked before
if (Double.TryParse(txtboxAmount.Text, out output)

And putting the code in a scope but this doesn't
if (Double.TryParse(txtboxAmount.Text, out output) && int.TryParse(decimelPlacetxtBox.Text, out input));

Comment: `if (!double.TryParse(txtboxAmount.Text, out double amount) || !int.TryParse(decimelPlacetxtBox.Text, out int decimalPlaces)) return;`. Otherwise, use the values. `double.TryParse()` fails when the decimal separator entered is not the one defined by the CurrentCulture. If you want to enforce the *dot* as decimal separator, specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as part of the `TryParse()` overload.

Comment: I've put that in but it still gives a validation error, just curious why are we using return?

Comment: Because you're of course executing this code in a method, `return` will halt the execution of other code. You can replace it with whatever you like.-- If you have a *validation error*, you need to post the exact content of the error. This, however, is unrelated to the question. If you have another question, delete this one and post another.

Comment: When you say replace what do you mean what would I replace? Just making sense of everything, I fixed it btw by changing where I create int decimalPlace

Comment: You could *replace* it with a notification, sent to the User, that the parsing has failed (not a valid input). Then return. Or add the rest of the code in the `else` block. Quite common pattern.

Comment: Such as a message box?